# React Native Expo: Couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm encountering a recurring error when attempting to build either a release or debug version of my Android app using Expo. All the solutions I've come across online involve ejecting from Expo, which is not my preferred course of action. Is there a way to resolve or circumvent this issue without having to eject from Expo?

The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main (from syncer thread)
not releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main (syncer thread started)
libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main
libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/app/~~104OcR1LXuRQKehmupXYzQ==/mz.co.wei.exames-btQ003aEHqmn80CTo2e1lw==/lib/arm64

couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so

SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main flags = 1]
SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
Native lib dir: /data/app/~~104OcR1LXuRQKehmupXYzQ==/mz.co.wei.exames-btQ003aEHqmn80CTo2e1lw==/lib/arm64
result: 0
```

It seems that other libs are also not found:

```
libhermes.so not found on /data/data/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main
libhermes_executor.so not found on /data/data/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main
libfbjni.so not found on /data/data/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main
libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main
libyoga.so not found on /data/data/mz.co.wei.exames/lib-main
```

Here are the dependencies:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gluestack-style/react": "^0.2.51",
    "@gluestack-ui/themed": "^0.1.53",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.18",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "moti": "^0.26.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-circular-progress-indicator": "^4.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-mathjax-html-to-svg": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0"
  }
```

- Ensured that all dependencies are compatible (react reanimated, gesture handler)
- Installed the missing modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by executing the `npx expo prebuild` command, which generated the iOS and Android folders. These folders contain essential build system configuration files. Following this, I included the Android `jsc-android` dependencies in the project-level `build.gradle` file. It's important to note that prior to this, I installed the `jsc-android` library using `npm install jsc-android` to make the library available in the `node_modules` folder. Here's the updated `build.gradle` code snippet:

```
maven {
  // Android JSC is sourced from npm
  url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
}
```

Comment: why would I run `prebuild`? I am using expo.dev and whenever I run `npx eas-cli build --platform android` it builds it on their own platform. So why would this local step have any impact?